# Display networkx graph in Tkinter after pressing button

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, networkx

Trying to get a simple Tkinter application to display a networkx graph when the user hits a button.  here's the code I have:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import copy
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg#, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)               
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def UploadAction(self,event=None):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes=(()))


    def runAnalysis(self,event=None):
        df = pd.DataFrame({'from': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E','F','F'], 'to': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A','C','B']})
        node_sizes = [2000,26400,2000,2000,2000,2000]
        node_colors = ['#3da4ab','#fe8a71','#3da4ab','#fe8a71','#f6cd61','#f6cd61']

        f = plt.figure(figsize=(5,4))
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        plt.axis('off')

        # Build your graph
        G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to')

        # Plot it
        nx.draw(G, node_size=node_sizes, node_color=node_colors, with_labels=True, linewidths=0, edgecolors='black')

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=self.master)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        #plt.show()


    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title('Title... ')
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        quitButton = Button(self, text="Quit",command=self.master.destroy)
        quitButton.place(x=0, y=0)
        uploadButton = Button(self,text="UploadFile",command=self.UploadAction)
        uploadButton.pack()

        runNetworkButton = Button(self,text="run analysis")
        runNetworkButton.pack()



r = tk.Tk()
r.geometry("800x400")
app = Window(r)
r.mainloop()
```

When I click the run analysis button, nothing happens.  Can anyone see what it is I'm doing wrong here?  My suspicion is that is has something to do with 
`canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=self.master)`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: run network button should call,  command=runAnalysis.

Comment: ARGH!!... so simple... thanks @JohnT -> not enough coffee today or something...